# Basic seperation of variables question: does it matter which sides we put the minus on?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, laplacian

Lets take the equation $\Delta u=0$, where $u=u(x,y)$, $\Delta $ is the laplacian in two dimensions (x and y), and $0<x<L, 0<y<L$. Lets assume homogenous Dirichlet boundary conditions in the x-direction. If we use seperation of variables, then we get $\frac{X(x)''}{X(x)}=-\frac{Y(y)''}{Y(y)}=-k^2$. Here is where I usually get into trouble: If we use the above standing seperation of variables then, we get $X_n(x)=\sin(k_nx), k_n=\frac{n\pi}{L}$. But we could just as easilly have seperated the variables so that we had gotten $-\frac{X(x)''}{X(x)}=\frac{Y(y)''}{Y(y)}=-k^2$, and then we would have gotten $X_n(x)=\sinh(k_nx)$ with some $k_n$.

My question is this: are those solutions equivallent, or not?

Thanks!

Comment: As you have it written, the $\sinh$ solution doesn't satisfy the BCs unless $k_{n} = 0$, making the solution trivial.

Comment: You don't have to use $k^2$. Use $k$ until you can find out the values of $k$ that will work with the endpoint condtions.

Comment: @mattos Alright, I think I see it now after your explanation. You can post your comment as an answer if you want, so can can accept the answer

Comment: @mattos So to generalize, we put the plus on the side with the variables which have homogenous boundary conditions (because of the Sturm-Louville thm). In other words, we put the plus on the side of X in my question. Would that be a correct interpretation?